# How to make a browser open 100 tabs at once without crashing?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, automation

I need to manually check the content of all hyperlinks on a webpage. It is tedious to click on each one of them. I find some plugin in Chrome web store, to open all hyperlinks. However this almost crashes the browser.

The appropriate way which will work without crashing is

1. List all hyperlinks
2. Open them one by one with a program

Is there any software out there which does this?

Comment: How does it "almost crashes the browser", or is it just that opening 100 webpages just takes some time?

Comment: Tabs use memory. Are you running out of memory?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-all-urls/djdmadneanknadilpjiknlnanaolmbfk Why not in batches of for example 20?

Comment: As @Gantendo suggests, create a numbered list of the URL's in a tool  such as LibreOffice *Writer*, select a batch at a time, open hyperlinks. Then **close the tabs in the browser** before opening the next batch. Alternative: get 128 GB of RAM to keep them all open at once, if the browser allow that.

Comment: Another alternative. Try another browser. Vivaldi is pretty good in doing this, though I haven't tried 100 tabs at once. But I have opened like 70 images as tabs at once without a problem (except that it took some time)

Comment: @LPChip I doubt the browser itself is the problem unless they use a weird addon. I just tested opening 300 urls in Firefox and Chrome and both work fine (13600K, 64gb RAM on Win11) although it takes a while.

Comment: What is "some plugin"? You need to be **as specific as possible** here. You also didn't mention how much RAM you have and how good your CPU is. Or what website it is or if you tried another (maybe this oner has more hidden ones and you try to open 1000 instead?). IMO very closable question.

Comment: Not that it is helpful (necessarily) but a programmer could do this through code in their sleep without trying to open them all at once.  If you know one and buy them a beer.. they might write it for you.

Comment: are you using windows?